# C#: Garbage collector

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

Is it necessary to do this poly = null; ? After finishing the function the Garbage Collector would clean up or ?

Here a simple example:

```
    public void redrawSingelPoly(Canvas canvas) 
    {
        Polyline poly = new Polyline();
        poly.Stroke = colorBrush;
        poly.StrokeThickness = basicLineThick;

        poly.Points = points;
        canvas.Children.Add(poly);

        poly = null; //Garbage Collector
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your poly object will NOT be garbage collected in your example.  Here is why...

You are doing the following...

```
canvas.Children.Add(poly);
```

Which keeps a reference to the object.  Even though you set your local reference to that object = null, there is still a reference to it that is passed out of the method!

The garbage collector only collects unreacheable objects.

That being said - Is it necessary to set poly = null?  No it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `poly` to `null` is unnecessary, at least for two reasons.

1. Since C# (and .net in general) is a managed memory environment, the memory for the variable will be done with automagically, by the garbage collector.
2. The garbage collector will not collect memory that is still in use, and if the `canvas.Children` property is in scope, so will be the memory used by the `Polyline` object, regardless of the value of the `poly` variable.

Comment: The garbage collector has nothing to do with the memory for the variable, that's reclaimed as soon as the method returns. The memory for the object that's *referenced by the variable*, that's another matter.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's not necesssary, but what warries me is :

```
canvas.Children.Add(poly);
```

this line. Not very clear what happens inside `Add(..)` method.

From the *scope* perspective `GC` will locate and collect all local variables that are not referenced by global refrences, so there is no sence of doing `=null`

Comment: “Not very clear what happens inside Add(..) method.” `Children` is a `UIElementCollection`, so its `Add()` method behaves the same as `Add()` of any other collection.

Comment: “GC will locate and collect all local variables” No, GC doesn't do that. It collects *objects* that are not referenced, not variables.

Comment: @svick: GC collects referencies, frees/*de*-fragments memory they pointed to. I strongly believe OP understands what I mean. "canvas" is a UIElementCollection ? : it's your idea, I don' see a clear evidence of it, and by the way don't know how internals of it works, that's why in my answer I *clearly mantioned that*, at least seemed to me.

Comment: I think that's the wrong way to look at it. After a method returns, the GC can't “locate and collect” its local variables, because they no longer exist. (And I think that it's pretty much certain that the types in the question are from WPF, but that's not really relevant.)